# How to save images to mongodb using multer.fields()?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multer

I am getting a no file or directory error when trying to save my uploaded files to mongodb. I have uploaded with Multer, can anyone help me on how i can solve this issue?

[this the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gUsl.png)

[this is the code (in the image) which is saving the images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsoaY.png)

i was expecting to save the image to mongodb.. however though, once before i used multer.single() it worked

```
but now with multer.fields() it is not working

below is the code i once used with multer.single()
```

productImage: {
data: fs.readFileSync("./public/" + req.file.filename),
contentType: "image/jpg"
},

```
please help.
```

Comment: req.files['songArtwork'] is returning an object instead of file name. Therefore, fs module could not parse file called `[Object object]` from `public` directory

Comment: So how can I get it to return a file name?